# Using AJAX with Ruby On Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, json

I have this function in my controller:

```
def showRecipeIngredients
    ingredients = RecipeIngredient.where( "recipe_id = ?", params[:id]).all
    @html = ""
    ingredients.each do |i|
        @html = @html + "<p>#{Food.find_by_ndb_no(i.ndb_no).long_desc} - #{i.quantity} #{i.units}</p>"
    end


# value of @html: <p>Cheese, parmesan, grated - 6.0 cup</p><p>Cheese, port de salut - 8.0 cup, diced</p><p>Salad dressing, russian dressing, low calorie - 45.0 tablespoon</p>

    result = @html
    render( :json => result )
end
```

And I'm making this AJAX call:

```
 $(".recipe_ids").click(function() {

    var id = parseInt( $(this).attr('id').substring(11) );

    alert("THIS ID: " + id);

    $.get( "/recipes/showRecipeIngredients?id="+id, function(result) {

 //things get weird over here
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
        var obj2 = <%= @html %>

        $("#search_results").html(result);
    }

 );
```

It's going through the controller function fine, but for some reason, I'm not getting back the HTML I want from the call. I'm getting nothing at all. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are sending html in the resp then set the dataType accordingly

```
$.get( "/recipes/showRecipeIngredients?id="+id, function(result) {

        //no need to parse json if its not json
        //var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
        var obj2 = <%= @html %>

        $("#search_results").html(result);
    },'html');//<-- set the dataType
```

Comment: Aha, that did the trick! Thank you! There really is no need to do an embedded `<%= @html %>` is there?

Comment: i really cant say but apparently there is no need